# How to make background colour consistent through a templated Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, templates

I have created a Word template with multiple pages. I have set the background colour to dark grey, and there are no sections in the document so this should be consistent through the document.

When viewing the template file (.dotx), all pages have a grey background.

When viewing the new document (.docx) created upon clicking the template file, only the first page has a grey background; the remainder have defaulted to a white background.

How do I make the grey background consistent across all pages on the .docx file?

Comment: The best solution I could find was to include a solid grey background image in the header (scaled to full page). Not ideal but it works for now.